# Build a nested interval loop

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I want to build an interval loop which triggers every day. Inside this loop should be again a interval loop, which triggers every 20 minutes. So now, I am curious, if I could just build it like this:

```
updatePeriodically() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Fetch daily sensor update!')
        getInitData()
            .then((results) => {
                this.setState({ dataSensor: results })      
            })
            window.setInterval(() => {
                console.log('Fetch 20 minute sensor update')
                getData()
                    .then((results) => {
                        this.setState({ dataSensor: results })
                })
            }, UPDATE_INTERVAL)

    }, DAILY_INTERVAL)
}
```

I just want to know, if this triggers a new 20 min-interval loop every day and does not stops the old one, so in the end after some days, I have like four 20-update loops? Or maybe someone knows, how to do this a better way?

Comment: Where is the updatePeriodically attached to? In a store/in a component, serverside? As you do not make a clearInterval I would say you would get multiple intervals, but it is hard to say with only the function (who knows, you might attach it to a render function in which case you will have much more than 20 update loops each time the setState causes a rerender of your components)

Comment: this function is triggered in 'componentDidMount()' so there are no other functions calling this update. So you mean, if i build it like above, the daily loop won't trigger every day a new 20-min loop or do I have to stop the 20-min loop first and then start a new one?

Comment: It would trigger a new 20 minutes loop on a daily basis, so you assumption as far as I can judge it, is correct, after a few days you will have plenty of 20 minutes intervals :) Btw, maybe this is just a copy/paste error, but you seem to be missing quite some semicolons making it a bit harder to read, try to use as much as possible `'use strict';` to catch possible hard to find errors early

Comment: thanks for that, I am going to use more semicolons :)

Comment: You're welcome, and btw, do you also call `window.clearInterval` when you get to the function `componentWillUnmount()`? I am guessing not as you do not save the intervals that window.setInterval is creating ;)

Comment: I actually never call ```componentWillUnmount()```. Is this necessary?

Comment: It is part of the components lifecycle in react, so you don't have to call it but you could use it to release the intervals

Comment: At which point to I call it? I have a dashboard application with live data, so is there actually a 'release of intervals' ?

Comment: So, I am assuming you are getting your data using a store. From my point of view, it would be better for the store to dispatch new data to components than the component(s) polling the store. Just to avoid more complex behavior at later times where you might need to reload the data for other active components as well. If the store is taking care of the refresh, then all components would get their updated data at once without having to wait for their independent intervals to trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you could refine your interval timer by either checking if the interval has already started before (your internal interval), or by using only one interval and repeat getInitdata only once every so many times, as such:

```
updatePeriodically() {
    var remaining = 0;
    window.setInterval(() => {
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            console.log('Fetch daily sensor update!');
            getInitData().then((results) => {
                this.setState({ dataSensor: results });
            });
            remaining = DAILY_INTERVAL;
        } else {
            remaining -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
            console.log('Fetch 20 minute sensor update');
            getData().then((results) => {
                this.setState({ dataSensor: results });
            });
        }
    }, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
}
```

this has the advantage that it would only use 1 loop to do the periodic updating, and no extra intervals will be started.

I would however recommend not creating this update loop inside a component. I am assuming the data you want to display is managed by a store, and you should rather have a central place that runs this "polling" update, so that all components get the new data at once, instead of each component implementing such a polling function. A bonus would be that all components that are dependent from this data get their new state data at the same time.